# Pass structure as an argument in c# method

Tags: c#, methods

I want to know if it is possible to pass a Structure as a parameter in c# method and if possible, is it a good practice to do so?

I have a c# method which is taking six arguments, i really hate that. I could create a carrier class for that and pass it as an argument, but i want to know if structure could do the job.

I want to mention here that few arguments to that method are of ref type and few are of value type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can do it, but you need to bear a couple of things in mind.

First is that a value type (struct) is stored on the stack (often, not always, see comment-thread), rather than the heap. The stack is limited in size and large objects shouldn't be stored on it. That said, there is a minor performance benefit to storing variables on the stack.

The next is that a value type passed as a method argument will be copied, rather than referenced. This can be a good thing. At least you know that your variable isn't going to be changed by the method. However, the copy is stored on the stack, so be careful. Also, sometimes you want a method to be able to edit the contents of your object.

Finally, you need to know that reference objects within a struct are just pointers to objects on the heap. So if you edit the contents of one of those classes (unless, like a string, they are coded to be immutable), you are going to affect the contents of your own object, even though it is supposedly immutable. This can be very confusing.

As soon as you said that some of the contents are reference objects, I thought "I'd just stick to a class."

As a general rule:

- Only use structs to hold other immutable objects.
- Only use structs for small collections of data.
- Only use structs where changing one item within it will probably change all of the others.

Take an address as a good example:

- All contents are strings and thus immutable.
- It's only a half-dozen pointers.
- While you might remain in the same zipcode, for example, if you move house then you probably change your entire address.

Comment: a value type is not necessarily stored on the stack

Comment: @jk: You mean that it could be boxed? Do you not think the answer is complicated enough? And, arguably, if it's boxed then it's no longer a value object, it's boxed inside a reference.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx

Comment: Yeah, ok, I see  your point. If you're already IN a reference object when you're calling the method then any member variable is on the heap. Again, all true, but overcomplicating the answer. The copy that is created would be on the stack and thus size matters and that's all I'm trying to get over. I will add a comment though.

Comment: No, the point is not that we should be uber-correct and enumerate how a structure object could be stored in which conditions (by the way, you neglect the option to use registers). The point is that it does not matter and thus shouldn't be mentioned at all. The important differences are the value *semantics* (what you call copying). Especially in this context -- a couple of method arguments should always be small enough for stack space taken to be no concern.

Comment: @delnan: I disagree quite strongly. I think if you're going to start messing around with structs, you need to know the effect of making one too large. Even a half dozen pointers makes quite a big object, if it's going to be copied repeatedly, and what about the next reader who wants to apply the same logic to a 20- or 50-parameter method?

Comment: Half a dozen pointers are 6 * 4 = 24 bytes (on 32 bit systems; but merely twice as much on 64 bit). You'd need 40 copies of those to even fill a KiB, where stacks are commonly one to a few MiB large. As for 20- or 50-parameter methods: If you have so many parameters, or object attributes, you have more urgent problems than a waste of stack space. That, coupled with the hope that so many members/parameters are exceptional, makes me think it's not worth adding this (otherwise irrelevant) information to every discussion of structs.

Comment: That last point is optimistic, in my experience, but really, it's clear we disagree and I'm fine with that. Feel free to write a more succinct answer, leaving out the stuff you think is irrelevant. But if you think implementation details are an irrelevant waste-of-space, then arguing exactly how many bytes is too many surely is.

Comment: I get that we disagree on the importance of that information. What I don't get is why you think it's important, and I'd like to know. As I outlined above, your arguments seem bogus to me. It would need outrageous and unlikely amounts of copying and parameters for stack space to become scarce (the specific numbers are just for our discussion, not for answering this question).

Comment: I've seen too many problems caused by developers with a new tool, using it everywhere without knowing what the framework will let you do, which you might want to think twice before doing. It's not even that these problems are frequent, it's that they're generally hell to find when they do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can (and should) have structures and classes as arguments to methods. This will help encapsulate your data and make it easier if you need to pass more data to your methods. You simply extend the class and recompile.

Obviously, just extending a class is to be avoided if it's a public interface, but if it's just internal to your application then there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: And Structure could do the same job as well even for reference type variables? Which approach is better if we could use both of them?

Comment: @MegaMind I'd use a class for preference, but you could use a structure quite happily.